# If a space tether/elevator is cut, will the severed pieces be flung out into outer space or will they fall on earth like shown in this video?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, angular-velocity

My thinking was that , they will be flung off into space.

Is that true, or will they all fall onto earth like shown in this video at around 49:51 onwards when a alien spaceship severs the space elevator ?
https://youtu.be/bMoxqg2Wr9I?t=2991

Comment: @J.G. Yep, and with judicious application of the Mean-Value Theorem :-),  there's a point at which the cut will leave everything as-is, albeit very unstable equilibrium.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Discontinuous as it sounds, I suspect a midway cut will lead to both disasters.

Comment: @J.G.  You're probably right -- need 2 cuts for a midsection to stay in orbit.  A single cut always sends the upper section outwards and the lower section crashes.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/697) (warning: NSFW language) while we're being humorous.

Comment: @J.G. You should post your comment as an answer. I think it is satisfactory for this question.

Comment: @Lawton OK, done.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where it's cut. To quote [*Kurzgesagt*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPQQwqGWktE), "If it breaks near the anchor, the force exerted by the counterweight will cause the entire elevator to rise up ascending into space. Should it break near the counterweight the tether will fail, wrapping around the world and whipping the end off. The resulting debris in orbit..."